# Dovecot add existent folder from command line

Tags: command, dovecot, line

I've insert a .INBOX.test folder in my mailbox folder /home/user/Maildir but I dont see it from Thunderbird.
What i have to do for see it?!
Thanks

Comment: IMAP? You need to subscribe to the folder, or set the toggle that subscribes to all folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the folder.

You can either do that from your email client (Thunderbird), or you can add the name of the folder to the file `subscriptions` in the `Maildir`.

```
echo INBOX.test >> /home/user/Maildir/subscriptions
```